# Why \g<0> behaves differently than \0 in re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python 3.3

```
re.sub("(.)(.)",r"\2\1\g<0>","ab")  returns baab
```

BUT

```
re.sub("(.)(.)",r"\2\1\0","ab")  returns ba
```

Is this a bug in the sub method or does the sub method not recognize \0 on purpose for some reason?

Comment: It's almost certainly not a bug in most senses of the word.

Comment: Seems related to http://bugs.python.org/issue17426

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [written on this page](http://bugs.python.org/issue17426), the `\0` is interpreted as the null character (`\x00`) and group number start at 1 in Python (according to the `re` module documentation):

> \number
>
> Matches the contents of the group of the same number. Groups are **numbered starting from 1**. For example, `(.+) \1` matches 'the the' or '55 55', but not 'thethe' (note the space after the group). This special sequence can only be used to match one of the first 99 groups. **If the first digit of number is 0**, or number is 3 octal digits long, **it will not be interpreted as a group match**, but as the character with octal value number. Inside the '[' and ']' of a character class, all numeric escapes are treated as characters.

Also, according to the page previously linked, it's not a bug but a desired behaviour (this is obvious, since it's documented).

Comment: Thank you.  Python Pocket Reference from Oreilly has wrong information for re.sub. It says for re.sub ...can also include sequence escapes \1,\2, ...or \0 for all.

Answer (score 1):

`\0` is interpreted as an escape for null `\x00`, and `re` does not recognize it as a capture group.

**Reference:**

[Python Standard Library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Curiously, it's not: `r"\0"` is `'\\0'`, a string of two printable characters. Apparently `re.sub` turns it into `\x00`?

Comment: @delnan: That's because the r specifies that that's a raw string - escaped characters will not be interpreted as the values they represent. `"\0"` should equal `\x00`.

Comment: I understand that part, I'm puzzled why `re.sub` doesn't leave that in place. Both OP's example and the example in the issue someone linked to use raw strings, yet stil have a 0 character in the output.

Comment: That I do not know the answer to. :?